# Insert a node at nth position in a linked list; what's wrong in this code?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have this function to insert new data at a specific position in a linked list, but it isn't working:

```
Node* InsertNth(Node *head, int data, int position) {
    struct Node *h = head; 
    struct Node *p = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    for (i=0; i<position; i++)   
        { h = h->next; }

    p->next = h;  // what's wrong in this line 
    h = p;        // what's wrong in this line
}
```

If I change `i=0` to `i=1` in the `for` loop and change `h` in the lines with the "what's wrong" comments to 
 `h->next`, the results are fine and I have seen many solutions for this question. Everyone does write `i=1` and `h->next` — but why not `i=0` and `h`?

Comment: This is not a good question. At the very least you should be specific about why you believe your code has a problem. Your question should also show that you have exhausted other methods of answering this question and done proper research. But that is the next level. First thing is to write your question properly.

Comment: Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Then ask your question properly.  Please note that it helps to indent your code.  In case of doubt, lay it out in the edit window as you want it to look (ignoring the preview, and ensure there are no tabs), then select the code and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it.  Now check the preview window.

Answer (score 4):

When inserting a node in the middle of a linked list, you need to update the `next` field of the *previous* node that is before the position to point at the *new* node.

When inserting a node in the front of a linked list, you need to update the list's *head* pointer to point at the *new* node, which now points at the *old* head in its `next` field.

You are not doing either of those things in your code, so `p` is effectively not being added to the list at all. You are just leaking its memory.

You are also not validating that `position` is within the bounds of the list.  If `position` is too large, your code will end up accessing a NULL pointer and crash.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
Node* InsertNth(Node **head, int data, int position) {
    if ((!head) || (position < 0)) return NULL;

    struct Node *h = *head;
    struct Node *prev = NULL;

    for(int i = 0; i < position; ++i) {
        if (!h) return NULL;   
        prev = h;
        h = h->next;
    }

    struct Node *p = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (!p) return NULL;

    p->data = data;

    p->next = h;
    if (prev) prev->next = p;
    if (*head == h) *head = p;

    return p;
}
```

```
Node *list = NULL;
// add nodes as needed...
...
Node *n = InsertNth(&list, data, position);
if (n) {
    // success 
} else {
    // error
}
```

Comment: I'm not nitpicking, only curious: many people seem adamantly opposed to casting the result of a call to `malloc()`. Do you do this for the sake of clarity, or because you are required to cast with C++, or for some other reason?

Comment: if (prev) prev->next = p;

Comment: your prev->next is same as "h" means u end up getting the same code?

Comment: @DavidBowling the cast is optional in C, but required in C++. But it is best to avoid `malloc()` in C++, use `new` instead (and use `std::list` instead of a manual linked list implementation).

Comment: @GAURAVKUNGWANI4-YrBTechMet `prev->next` **originally** points to `h`, but since `p` is being inserted in front of `h`, `prev->next` needs to point to `p`, and then `p` points to `h`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  i am ok with it but  why not  -- p points to h and then h points to p.

Comment: @RemyLebeau leave it, i am very confused (and unable to delete previous comment)

Comment: @GAURAVKUNGWANI4-YrBTechMet if `p` pointed to `h` and `h` pointed to `p`, that would be a circular reference, not a linked list. Since you are clearly confused about linked lists work, I suggest you get paper and pencil and draw it out. And then after you figure it out, rewrite your code to use `std::list` instead, let it do all of the work for you.